# Why i cant join string with first value of dictionary?

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I would like to ask that why cant i join the string with the first value of the dictionary?

```
Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"cat", 0},
    {"dog", 1},
    {"llama", 2},
    {"iguana", 3}
};

string z = string.Join("Test_", d.Select(x => x.Value + "\n"));
```

These are the value of Z now

```
0
Test_1
Test_2
Test_3
```

Comment: Read the docs what string.Join is doing. To me that is the expected result

Comment: Well you *can*, however it won´t return what you *expect*.

Comment: What is your expected result? If you want Test_cat,Test_dog then you cant use `x.Value`, as those are the keys of the Dictionary

Comment: @HimBromBeere thats what i said :) "you cant use x.Value"

Comment: @TheSkimek But that is not the question. „Why can‘t I join the **first** value ...“

Comment: @SirRufo and thats why i asked "Whats your expected result" to get some carlification. It could very well be possible that OP sees the Keys of the dictionary as the "first value". He might have trouble to explain it correctly or is not fluent enough in englisch.

Comment: Please be more specific on your expected behaviour.

Comment: @TheSkimek The OP expected to see Test_0 instead of 0 at the first line from the first value. He wants to join the string (Test_) with the values but it did not for the first value

Comment: Thanks for all the comment.
Maybe i should have stated more clearly, my expected value was Test_0, Test_1, Test_2 and Test_3.  
Its just that i am wondering that why cant i join the first value with test meanwhile others are working

Comment: As to the *why you can´t do this*, that´s what Paolo wrote in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [String.Join documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) first.

You need use String.Concat, instead of String.Join.

Differences:

- String.Concat just union collection of strings to the final string. E.g. `String.Concat(new []{"1", "2", "3"})` returns "123"
- String.Join additionally adds separator between items. So, `String.Join(", ", new []{"1", "2", "3"})` returns "1, 2, 3".

So, you asked to use "Test_" as separator. Of course, separator does not added before the first argument. To add it, please use `string.Concat(d.Select(x => "Test_" + x.Value + "\n"));`

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! Totally got it now.

Answer (score 1):

`string.Join` concatenates the strings with specified value. What you want is to prepend a value to all of the strings, so use `String.Concat` instead:

```
string z = string.Concat(d.Select(x => "Test_" + x.Value + "\n"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

The `string.Join` method puts the separator **between** the elements of your sequence, not in front of each of them. So, for example

```
string[] values = new[] { "one", "two" };
string x = string.Join(" and ", values);
```

will produce `"one and two"`, not `"and one and two"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Got the idea now

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a clever mood, you can stream out all the characters using `SelectMany` (a string is also an `IEnumerable<char>`) and construct the concatenated string that way.

```
var z = new string( d.SelectMany( x => x.Value.ToString("Test_0\n")).ToArray());
```